# pass input value to stored procedure of telerik report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, telerik

I have created a report using telerik.  This report calls a Stored Procedure.  This Stored Procedure expects a value as an input, so should I pass this value through my C# windows form application?

I created a telerik report viewer and I imported my report to it.  I want to pass my value to the report but I don't know how to do that. I googled and I found something like this

```
Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameter asa=new ReportParameter();
asa.Value = "2";
//how can i assign this value to reportviewer????!!!!
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But this code doesn't assign my value to the reportviewer